# Why didn't Marshall and Lily receive the check?

Tags: plot-explanation, how-i-met-your-mother

In the television series, [*How I Met Your Mother*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460649/), S08E11, Lily and Marshall go to the storage room of the shop of an old friend. It looks weird to them and freak out.

Their friend brings up a check of an heavy amount to give it to them, but when he discovers that lily and Marshall were trying to kill him. He starts speaking, goes on. At the end he tares of the check, Why?

Why didn't he give them the cheque he brought for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole episode is about people trying to impress the people from their past. Ted tries to win over the professor with his new building and Daryl wants to impress Lily and Marshall with his business. However, after Marshall and Lily turn him down, he realises "he doesn't need the validation of some people he met in college". The money he wanted to give them was to get them to like him more/get them to acknowledge that he is a success. He no longer needs them to think he's cool so he just keeps the money.